# Mule Flow Reference Component throwing TransformerMessagingException while passing json

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have two flow one receive the xml payload and another json. I am routing the xml call to json flow using mule flow reference component after converting the xml to json payload. and second flow returns the json payload that i need to convert back to xml and reply to client.

My mule flow reference is throwing TransformerMsgException while receiving the json response from second flow.

```
Failed to transform from "json" to "java.lang.String" (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: String
```

Here are the code for your reference -

```
 <flow name="post:/chkdb:application/json:chkd-config">
         <logger message="========json payload==&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;====  #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         <set-variable variableName="GGG_Number" value="#[json:ggg]" doc:name="Variable"/>
                 <!--  db call returns the payload-->
         <choice doc:name="Choice">
             <when expression="#[message.payload.size()&gt;0]">
                 <set-payload value="{&quot;indicator&quot;:&quot;True&quot;}" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
             </when>
             <otherwise>
                 <set-payload value="{&quot;indicator&quot;:&quot;False&quot;}" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
             </otherwise>
         </choice>
         <logger message="=========after producing json output=======" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     </flow>
     <flow name="post:/chkdb:application/xml:chkdb-config">
         <logger message="========= xml payload========  #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         <json:xml-to-json-transformer mimeType="application/json" doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
         <flow-ref name="post:/chkdb:application/json:chkdb-config" doc:name="post:/chkdb:application/json:chkdbapi-config"/>  <!-- Getting exception here -->
         <logger message=" after subflow call ==== #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         <json:json-to-xml-transformer mimeType="application/xml" doc:name="JSON to XML"/>
         <logger message="after json to xml conversion" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     </flow>
```

XML Request -

```
<ggg>DeJmp03bkqALlRFYmgu4+A==</ggg>
```

How i should retrieve the json response from other flow to current flow.

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing here

- First flow name: post:/chkdb:application/json:**chkdbapi-config**
- Second flow name: post:/chkdb:application/xml:chkdbapi-config
- Flow ref in second flow: post:/chkdb:application/json:**chkdb-config**

You are not referencing First flow.

Comment: I have updated the flow name, earlier edited to remove the original project specific names.

Comment: Can you paste an exmple of your incoming XML? Im not able to reproduce your error

Comment: <ggg>DeJmp03bkqALlRFYmgu4+A==</ggg>   updated in question also, Thanks

Comment: So, I'm not getting the same error that you..But it works fine to me just changing the Choice condition to: #[message.payload.length>0]

Comment: Are u able to reach back to xml flow after doing that( to "after subflow call" log component)? surprising. we have changed the payload to json after choice router, and i was not getting back to application/xml flow. ill test and update.

Comment: I have changed choice condition but still the control is not reaching to "after subflow call' log component. flow reference is throwing exception.

Comment: Yep, it works fine for me. I cant reproduce your error :S. Which Mule and Anypoint version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

So from your flow posted I can find few issues as follows :-
1. You are using  where is the flow post:/chkdb:application/json:chkdb-config doesn't exits and it should be post:/chkdb:application/json:chkdbapi-config instead
2. Right now in the flow you are using `<when expression="#[message.payload.size()&gt;0]">` where as the message payload is in String format right now.
So, you can either use `<when expression="#[message.payload.length()&gt;0]">`, using **length()** instead of **size()** or put a `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>`before choice if you use `#[message.payload.size()&gt;0]`

So the full code will be something as follows :-

```
 <flow name="post:/chkdb:application/json:chkdbapi-config">
          <logger message="========json payload==&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;====  #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
       <!--   <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/> --> <!-- incase you use #[message.payload.size()&gt;0] in your choice -->
                  <!--  db call returns the payload-->
    <set-variable variableName="GGG_Number" value="#[json:ggg]" doc:name="Variable"/>    
          <choice doc:name="Choice">
              <when expression="#[message.payload.length()&gt;0]">
                  <set-payload value="{&quot;indicator&quot;:&quot;True&quot;}" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
              </when>
              <otherwise>
                  <set-payload value="{&quot;indicator&quot;:&quot;False&quot;}" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
              </otherwise>
          </choice>
          <logger message="=========after producing json output=======" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      </flow>

      <flow name="post:/chkdb:application/xml:chkdbapi-config">
          <logger message="========= xml payload========  #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
          <json:xml-to-json-transformer mimeType="application/json" doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
          <flow-ref name="post:/chkdb:application/json:chkdbapi-config" doc:name="post:/chkdb:application/json:chkdbapi-config"/>  <!-- Getting exception here -->
          <logger message=" after subflow call ==== #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
          <json:json-to-xml-transformer mimeType="application/xml" doc:name="JSON to XML"/>
          <logger message="after json to xml conversion" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
      </flow>
```